# Visual Studio 2017 - UWP Error for reference packages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the below error when trying to run the UWP app on local machine.

> Your project is not referencing the "UAP,Version=v10.0.10240" framework. Add a reference to "UAP,Version=v10.0.10240" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore

When I checked the project.json file, the required reference is already added there. See below project.json file.

```
"frameworks": {
"uap10.0.10240": {}
```

}

Then why I am still getting the error ? Also my application versions are set follows,

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Can I anyone please explain what is the exact issue and how to resolve it ?

Comment: This is usually caused by some faulty NuGet references. Could you post the whole contents of your `project.json` file and list the NuGet packages you are using?

Answer (score 0):

From msdn:

There is a hot fix for this issue: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.BuildTasks, copy&paste all dlls and overwrite all files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0.